# LSTM with CRF in Keras

Tags: scikit-learn, keras, lstm, crf, crfsuite

I don't really understand how to combine sklearn_crfsuite and Keras.

I have to made a classic LSTM and insteed of the last Activation, I use sklearn_crfsuite?

Someone have an example?

Thx,

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into the [keras-contrib](https://github.com/farizrahman4u/keras-contrib) package, which has an implementation of CRF as a Keras layer.

Comment: here is an example for the package: https://confusedcoders.com/data-science/deep-learning/how-to-build-deep-neural-network-for-custom-ner-with-keras